# Multiple Endpoints for Prometheus in Go

Tags: go, microservices, prometheus, exporter

I'm currently working on a program written in `Go (golang)` that is monitored by Prometheus.

Now the program should serve two endpoints `/metrics` and `/service`.
When scraped by Prometheus on `/metrics`, it should expose it's own metrics (e.g. requests made, request latency, ...) and when scraped on `/service`, it should query an API, get metrics from there and expose them to Prometheus.

For the first part I create e.g. a Counter via

```
requestCount := kitprometheus.NewCounterFrom(stdprometheus.CounterOpts{
    Namespace: "SERVICE",
    Subsystem: "service_metrics",
    Name:      "request_count",
    Help:      "Number of requests received.",
}, fieldKeys)
```

and serve the stuff via:

```
http.Handle("/metrics", promhttp.Handler())
http.ListenAndServe(":8090", nil)
```

for the `/service` part, I query the API, extract a value and update a different Gauge via `Gauge.Set(value)`

- How do I expose this last Gauge on the different endpoint without
  firing up another server (different port)?
- Do I have to create my own Collector (I have no custom metrics, so
  no, right?)?

Comment: Yes, you should implement a collector for the /service endpoint (your program assumes the role of an exporter for the API). First, check if one is already available at https://prometheus.io/docs/instrumenting/exporters/. Then read https://prometheus.io/docs/instrumenting/writing_exporters/.

Comment: Thanks @Peter , that's all I wanted to know... even though I hoped there was a different possibility without writing additional code... :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `prometheus.NewRegistry` to create a custom collector, and expose it to some endpoint you want by using `promhttp.HandlerFor`.

```golang
var (
        // custom collector
        reg = prometheus.NewRegistry()
        // some metrics
        myGauge = prometheus.NewGaugeVec(
                prometheus.GaugeOpts{
                        Name: "gauge_name",
                        Help: "guage_help",
                },
                []string{"l"},
        )
)

func init() {
        // register metrics to my collector
        reg.MustRegister(myGauge)
}

func main() {
        // instrument
        myGauge.WithLabelValues("l").Set(123)

        // expose endpoint
        http.Handle("/service", promhttp.HandlerFor(reg, promhttp.HandlerOpts{}))
}
```